# Python - Retrieve all of the functions under multiple classes in a package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have a package structure like that:

```
common/
    a.py
    b.py
    c.py
    __init__.py
    .svn
util/
    util.py
    __init__.py
```

I want to write a function in util.py to retrieve all of the functions in a.py, b.py, c.py

```
from os import listdir

files = listdir(directory_to_common)
for f in files:
    if '.py' in f and '__' not in f:
        module_name = f.split(.)[0]
        module = __import__(module_name)
```

I can successfully import the module.

Than I used

```
inspect.getmembers(module)
```

but it returns a lot of un-needed information.
From here, how do I retrieve the functions inside a.py, b.py, c.py?

```
#a.py, b.py, c.py has similar structure as follows:
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        .....
    def method1_in_a(self):
        .....
    def method2_in_a(self):
        .....
```

Comment: What do you mean by "functions"?  Functions defined using `def`? Instances of `function`? Any callables?

Comment: @Goyo I mean to return all the method, method1_in_a, method2_in_a, etc in each class inside ech py files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return only needed information, use the optional argument `predicate`. Example to find all classes in a module and all functions in a class:

```
classes = inspect.getmembers(module, predicate=inspect.isclass)
for cls_name, cls in classes:
    functions = inspect.getmembers(cls, predicate=inspect.isfunction)
        for fn_name, fn in functions:
            print(cls_name, fn_name)
```

For a list of all available predicates, see [inspect module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) (all the functions named `inspect.isXYZ` are predicates).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import inspect
from os import listdir
files = listdir(directory_to_common)
functions = [inspect.getmembers(__import__("{}.{}".format(directory_to_common, i[:-3])), inspect.isfunction) for i in files if i.endswith('.py') and not i.startswith('__')]
```